# Bidirectional asynchronous replication with 3 clusters in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

I have 3 clusters with 3 nodes each. All 3 clusters are linked using bidirectional bootstrap replication. I am doing some stress test.
Scenario 1:  An outage has occurred in one of the datacenters and one of the clusters in down- All 3 nodes down. After the outage, the nodes came backup, but it now does not have all the data that was added to the table. How can this cluster easily catchup with the other 2 clusters in the universe?

We have the following design and we expect users from each location to connect locally to the corresponding cluster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Daisy chaining, which involves connecting a series of universes as both source and target, for example: `A<>B<>C` is not supported yet. (from https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/architecture/docdb-replication/async-replication/#more-complex-topologies)

Please read the full page here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/architecture/docdb-replication/async-replication/

> Currently, it is the responsibility of the end user to ensure that a sink cluster has sufficiently recent updates so that replication can safely resume. In the future, bootstrapping the sink cluster can be automated #11538.